# Coalesce SQL output when one field has multiple values

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a list of emergency contacts for students in our school district. I would like to include their names and phone numbers. The phone number field in the database has multiple phone numbers stored for each student.

So if I run the following query :

```
Select name, number
From student
```

My Results look like this (I'm using made up numbers and names):

```
Alex A. 235-777-8888
Alex A.   235-777-8878
Alex A.  235-777-8899
Sarah B. 435-777-9999
Sarah B. 435-777-9988
```

What I would like my result to look like would be:

```
Alex A. 235-777-8888, 235-777-8878, 235-777-8899
Sarah B. 435-777-9999, 435-777-9988
```

Basically I just want each student name listed once followed by all of the numbers associated with them.

Any suggestions? I am pretty new to both SQL and programming in general, so the simpler the solution the better!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This is called aggregate string concatenation.  This has nothing to do with `coalesce()`, so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: We use Flyspeed SQL query. Sorry for taking so long to respond, the notification from Stack Overflow went to my spam folder.